# Sort an Option String

Tags: code-golf, string

### Background

In C, there is a function to help parse command-line arguments: `getopt`.

Getopt takes the argument count (`argc`), the argument list (`argv`), and a string representing the options the program should take (**`optstring`**).

The option string (`optstring`) is a series of option characters each followed by one colon (for an option requiring an argument), two colons (for an option with an optional argument), or zero colons (for an option without an argument).

For example: one might use the following option string for their company's new widget.

```
"v::x:hy:S:G::dns:f::"
```

But that looks horrible! The options are all mixed together! This option string would look much better if it were sorted:

```
"f::G::v::S:s:x:y:dhn"
```

### Specifications

- The input will be a string matching the regular expression `([A-Za-z]:{0,2})+`
- You should take input as a string or list of characters.
- You should output the string sorted by the method detailed below.
- You do not need to handle empty input.
- You do not need to handle input with repeated options of the same type (`"aa"` is not valid, but `"aa:a::"` is valid).

#### Sorting Method

In the sorted option string:

- The characters followed by two colons come first, sorted alphabetically, with uppercase letters before their respective lowercase letters (i.e. "aBb", not "Bab").
- Then are the characters with one colon, sorted alphabetically, with uppercase letters before their respective lowercase letters.
- Last are the characters with no colon, sorted alphabetically, with uppercase letters before their respective lowercase letters.

### Rules

- [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes in each language wins.

### Examples

```
# "input" => "output"
"v::x:hy:S:G::dns:f::" => "f::G::v::S:s:x:y:dhn"
"aa:a::" => "a::a:a"
"B:" => "B:"
"Confusio:n::" => "n::o:Cfinosu"
"Confusio:n:" => "n:o:Cfinosu"
"m:qW:X:xc:vViI" => "c:m:W:X:IiqVvx"
"V:omo:V" => "o:V:moV"
"agg:ra:va::ting::" => "a::g::a:g:aginrtv"
"input" => "inptu"
```

[Long test case](https://pastebin.com/yuq8F2bh) (312 characters)

Invaid Inputs (you don't have to handle):

```
"gg" (duplicated option)
"" (empty string)
":w:" (first colon isn't after a character)
"x:y:0:fhn" ('0' is not alphabetic)
"A:::" (3 colons is invalid)
```

Comment: `agg:ra:va::ting::` broke mine heh... Ironic.

Answer (score 10):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
ΣÖom_↔Oġλ¬√
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkPuoqfHQtv/nFh@elp8b/6htiv@Rhed2H1rzqGPW////y6ysKqwyKq2CrdytrFLyiq3SrKy4EhOtEoGUkxWXc35eWmlxZr5VnhUKhyvXqjDcKsKqItmqLCzTkyvMKj833yqMKzE93aoo0aoMqL0kMy8dqCkzr6C0BAA)

### Explanation

```
ΣÖom_↔Oġλ¬√  Implicit input, say "kH::r:R:Hk:"
       ġ     Split between characters for which this gives a falsy result:
        λ      Take two arguments, ignore the first.
          √    Is the second argument a letter?
         ¬     Negate.
             Now we have the options: ["k","H::","r:","R:","H","k:"]
      O      Sort: ["H","H::","R:","k","k:","r:"]
 Ö           Sort by
     ↔       reversing and
  om_        converting everything to lowercase: ["H::","k:","R:","r:","H","k"]
Σ            Concatenate: H::k:R:r:Hk
```

Comment: There are a couple of really clever ideas here, you should add an explanation so people can appreciate them :D

Comment: @Leo Added a breakdown of the code.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
f".:*" ñ_iZw vÃq
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ZiIuOioiIPFfaVp3IHbDcQ==&input=Im06cVc6WDp4Yzp2VmlJIg==)

#### How it works

Say the input string is `v:vg::G:G::o:`. The first part of the code, `f".:*"`, finds all matches of the regex `/.:*/g`, which matches a character followed by any number of colons. This splits the input into `[v:, v, g::, G:, G::, o:].`

The `ñ` method on an array sorts each the array as if certain changes were applied, without actually applying them (like `sorted(array, key=<whatever>)` in Python). So we need to sort:

- double-colons before everything else;
- single-colons after double-colons, but before no-colons;
- letters in their alphabetical order; and finally
- uppercase letters before lowercase.

`Z{ZiZéJ v}` is the shortest way I could find to do this:

```
  Zw     Reverse Z.
     v   Convert to lowercase.
Zi       Insert this at the beginning of Z.
```

This is easiest to understand with some examples:

```
         v:   v  g::    G:   G::    o:
  Zw     :v   v  ::g    :G   ::G    :o
     v   :v   v  ::g    :g   ::g    :o
Zi       :vv: vv ::gg:: :gG: ::gG:: :oo:
```

The original values are then sorted lexicographically by these keys. The result is that `::gG::` is sorted to the front, then `::gg::`, and so on, giving us `[G::, g::, G:, o:, v:, v]`, which is then joined with `q` and outputted.

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 47 bytes

```
.
$&$&
T01`L`l`..
O^`\w.:*
.(.)
$1
O$^`\w:*
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY49C8IwFEX39ztiqA4Pu95RhyIIHZToIJKgNgZsov2I9dfHODpdzoEDt7sNzps0KyqdmIQUkvbLUm/1QzNTfdanN2NBXPCcREm1@JksBMuUIjDh/sEOFXD1PRqAjIHJswKtg2/G3gV4/AG1eB1wxHRBVG5DCqENUGSsRWcQc55P2Rw5/xyHLw)

The trickiest part was actually sorting the letters, because Retina's "sort-by" feature doesn't have a case-insensitive sort (so by default it sorts the upper case letters in front of *all* lower case letters). To work around this, I had to insert a lower-case copy of each character to do the sorting and then get rid of it again.

Comment: Has a case-insensitive sort been added somewhere in the last year? And if not, is there a way to sort case-insensitive, but retain original order? I.e. `tEsTiNg` with your above sorting method sorts the pairs of letters to `eEggiinNsstTtt → EgiNsTt` instead of `eEggiinNsstttT → EgiNstT ` (the uppercase letters are always placed before the lowercase letters).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You can do it with sort-by now, because you can easily transform the character to lowercase in the substitution string. https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8N9fJUGPSyVHRe3//xLX4pBMv3QA

Comment: Ah, nice. Would have never thought of that myself.. Thanks a lot. I've been able to fix [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178898/52210) now. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>100</s> 90 bytes

```python
lambda s:''.join(sorted(re.findall('.:*',s),key=lambda s:(-len(s),s.lower(),s)))
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYy9DsIgGEX3PgUbYCqD4006OfgAri4YforSjwaw2qfHujRxuznn5M5rHROdmhtuLerpbjQr4Fw9UiBRUq7WiGyVC2R0jIIrHHhfZP@067D34hjtVsu@qJjeNottSSm7MM3bA8u2zTlQZU7wBfhgXHHFBTBU4AAuu92fE7lXCQn0z7X3yBqLBmog/5PtCw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
n”:œṗ⁸ṢŒuÞṚLÞṚ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/vUcNcq6OTH@6c/qhxx8Odi45OKj087@HOWT5g8v///0q5VoXhVhFWFclWZWGZnkoA)

Full program.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 69 + 1 (`-n`) = 70 bytes

```perl
say sort{$b=~y///c<=>length$a||($"=lc$a)cmp lc$b||1-2*($"ne$a)}/.:*/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYuxCsIwFEX3fIVIBhVqrNDlYh10EAcnobrG2sZA@1KbWCxWP92Y1emee@A0RVsl3lvZj6xp3Ytf0k8vhMhX6boqSLkbl8Mw4eO0yrmc5nUzCnAZhjhazoKmIti3mGMmlPcd8MStxxE74EoWJcCkhAyzAdsaKh9WGxD@DqtxP@GMZ44u03uWwdQGGZNKoZXoQu40qRBpah7uaxqnDVkfHZL5Il74iH4)

Comment: Each capital comes before its lowercase. E.g. 'AaBb'. I think changing `=~/A-Z/` to `==/A-Z/` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 93 bytes

```js
f=
s=>s.match(/\w:*/g).sort((a,b)=>b.length-a.length||parseInt(a,36)-parseInt(b,36)||a>b).join``
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=this.value&&f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <s>232</s> 213 bytes

```
s(){ s=${1#?} c=${1%$s} o=${s%%[^:]*} s=${s#$o} o=$c$o;};
p()(s $1;l= g= p=$o d=$c;[[ $o ]]&&(while s $s;[[ $o ]];do
(((x=${#o}-${#p},y=36#$d-36#$c,x?x:y?y:62#$c-62#$d)>0))&&g+=$o||l+=$o;done;echo `p $g`$p`p $l`))
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##VZBhb9MwEIa/51ecXLeyYdXYkPbhMq@CAVPFBNImBaRS1JCkjqXWzuI2JOry28u5pWh88T333qu7V/6V@nK/90LuwCu@uxhMesgCDLnvwRH54XD2E@ev@oPBD7g76Bl3cR9HlZDCA7@IVwq0gkpxBzlN49kMCOfz0Uj8Ls2qAHL5f2qcu0gI0dLGgevH9Fb9WafeXg14Pg5vdtZOWuwmHV5dUjcOby5v3kg5GunXdOX5eRUKLbJFXGSlg0UFXC94FepqIeX@QYmvn@HTu@m9jI4Z6iLNwUALRQgAYOi@OT//wXooCIsDkl4rLmiLkcQhcg0KeEG5qT/cYtwElTS@e5jxybxnUUgC19cfv3yAiDWILZYdPuIdYm49LhEZqBtgBCTR/BE9eTrMS8silqaYniwE1JH4/q9ANWK3zi633ji0Jx@Bw9ulsc5v/zec5i/Ha3z6ht@xzbBJzPToyHCNQZyap6RpyZSgWztMjlMCXLskpNMa6xQbSrYxVr8IqkNWjak2tt40ZDW22m6OY8INXaYf2f8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 124 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
import Data.Char
s(c:x)|(l,r)<-span(==':')x=(-length l,toLower c,c:l):s r;s _=[]
t(_,_,x)=x
f=(t=<<).sort.s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBbS8MwFMff@ykORTDBbh/guAg6UQbzaVAFkRFqL8E2mTlpzcDvPk872XwwD@fyz@9ckkbTR9m2h4Ppds4HuNdBz9eGQvJXWDbaJyQKjPJbtJmXixnttBVKXeKljErM2tLWoYE2C27tvkoPRVZgK5HAXxNs1etbEsQ222ZRqphUSgS1WMg58Yg5HUJJgdRrAnxEOiBGbPa4wUfEd0tYIaYZpOxY4NsNEhN7fG9sKrPfKq1RHzl2HJ9v7iaV7UlZOlv1ZBzaYwU7h8vKWEf9v9QR@ofp8PMZXzAWOORmNWIFdjhKK/OZD/FM5ug6h/mIsMPO5X92r2v0GgfePBhbn55Rjy@pUdfG@jCceWN3fRgZDgJvM8lvSTL@I0TQlkABI5vg1xYugBr3xfrVFaQwgxu2HE6iqCBKzqYOpgJOQampQ2hKy6RwHzKFsqVyTB5uV2uZTnTSaWN5Tqd3T1sQvS167/cw7iAnS4cf)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 152 bytes

```cs
s=>{var o="";for(var d=":::";d!="";){d=d.Substring(1);for(var c='@';c!=90;o+=s.IndexOf(c+d)>=0?c+d:"",s=s.Replace(c+d,""),c^=' ')if(c<97)c++;}return o;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBda8IwFH3Pr7j2xYY6cU/DW@PGBhvCxsYE3dMgJqkGauKStFPE396lVgYbeTjce764Ef5KWKcaUXLv4e1IdtWq1AJ84CFCbbWEF65NSuFI5gcf1Hb4WBkx8cFpsx5Ah1MoWOPZ9FhzB5YlSV5Yl7aDZAkiJrnstVt6lEwO59Wqs6XX9FcoWP@un4seG49ymzE/nBmp9q9FKjJJp2x0GxGTZOAj9a52JReqpQZJQgfik/WhT3UUT8Y3VGRZfnIqVM6AzU9NTr43ulSQBlep9hCAtlGbXRWAweWsB2u8LVUM5/JZG5XSPAp1AelFyCB2QZfbUv98S6eDOhuLzkFjwKl9TY24x80B5/iEKI3HApFwjjzCPZKYUFReWzT4ZyBb/FriB@4F1gs9Iwu0W4sLwtdrdBzraA/xF6Pp3Ed@AA)

Ungolfed:

```cs
s => { 
    var o = ""; 
    for (var d = ":::"; d != "";) { 
        d = d.Substring(1); 
        for (
            var c = '@'; 
            c != 90; 
            o += s.IndexOf(c + d) >= 0 ? c + d : "", s = s.Replace(c + d, ""), c ^= ' '
        ) if (c < 97) c++; 
    } 
    return o; 
}
```

The basic idea is to iterate over all 156 possible options and check for their existence.  If found, append to the output, and remove from the input.