# Generate a password

Tags: code-golf, word-puzzle

It is very hard to remember my password, so I came up with a way to generate a password.

The way I generate my password is from a word or a sentence, following these steps:

1. Start from left to right
2. Find the count of each letter
3. Put letter with its count in an order

   - Letters with higher repetition will be in the end
   - Letters with the same repetition will be ordered alphabetically
4. Numbers and special letters will be ignored including whitespace (e.g. 9, 4, @, (, *, etc. are ignored)
5. Group letters ignoring case. In the output, use the case of the last occurrence in the input
6. The count of the letter can be any number e.g. 5H17M345K
7. If input is all numbers or special letters then output will be empty string e.g. Input "12$*34^!" then output ""
8. when order for the same occurrence alphabetically case does not matter e.g. 1a1B1c

Example:

```
Input: Kitkat Tango
(2k / 1i / 3T / 2a / 1n / 1g / 1o)
Output: 1g1i1n1o2a2k3T
```

Another example:

```
Input: Database Partitions Task
(1D / 5a / 4T / 1b / 3s / 1e / 1P / 1r / 2i / 1o / 1n / 3s / 1k)
Output: 1b1D1e1k1n1o1P1r2i3s4T5a
```

Note: the letters with 1 repeat are in the beginning ordered alphabetically
then the letters with more reps

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code wins.

Comment: By 'count in each letter', do you mean how many times a letter appears in the input sentence?

Comment: Can a letter appear more than 9 times?

Comment: Can we output as an array? e.g., `["1g","1i","1n","1o","2a","2k","3T"]` or even `[["1","g"],["1","i"],["1","n"],["1","o"],["2","a"],["2","k"],["3","T"]]`

Comment: "Numbers and special letters will be ignored including whitespace (e.g. 9, 4, @, (, *, etc. are ignored)" - does this mean `[a-z][A-Z]` only?

Comment: "Letters with the same repetition will be ordered alphabetically" - usually 'D' sorts before 'a', so here do you explicitly mean "...ignoring case" or would `1D1P1b1e1k1n1o1r2i3s4T5a` be an acceptable output for "Database Partitions Task"?

Comment: Why was this put on hold? Maybe the question was initially not very nicely formatted, but it's clear enough to understand and the formatting has been fixed.

Comment: @BMO, I voted to close because [shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)'s high voted [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/178888/generate-password-code-golf/178907#comment431160_178888), which may make a difference in choosing the strategy. Is irritating to find out after you worked out and posted a solution that is either invalid or overcomplicated. I hope the OP will not take the close personally, after all there are 12 up and 0 downvotes.

Comment: @manatwork: But that's not unclear (note, their answer didn't assume that letters appear less than 10 times), it's just trying to loosen the input restrictions.

Comment: @BMO, neither of the questions I asked would make a difference to my own solution ;) Currently, though, by what's included in the challenge, it's not *explicitly* clear whether or not there's an upper limit on the number of times any one letter can appear in the input. Personally, I would assume not but others could easily assume otherwise.

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Yes

Comment: @Shaggy Yes, it can appear as many as possible it will be 12e for example

Comment: @Shaggy No, the output as the examples above only

Comment: @JonathanAllan yes a-z and A-Z only

Comment: @JonathanAllan case will be ignored in the order, D is before g so it will be 1D1g

Comment: @manatwork nothing personal, i hope the question is clear enough

Comment: make sure to add these clarifications to the actual question body, so answerers don't have to hunt through the comments

Comment: May I assume input will always be non-empty after removing non-alpha characters? e.g. input wont be `"123"`, `""` ect.

Comment: @tsh if input is all number then output will be empty string

Comment: Comments do not a specification make. You need to update the challenge to `1.` add at least 1 test case that includes more than 9 occurrences of one or more letters, `2.` specify that output must be a string (although I'd strongly recommend against being that strict; it adds nothing to the challenge), `3.` specify that we must be able to handle inputs containing no letters, and, `4.` clarify whether or not we need to handle an empty string as input.

Comment: Once you've done that then you will then have to test all existing solutions and inform them if they need to make any changes. I've already found quite a number of solutions that fail on point `1`. Also, in the future you might consider using [our Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/) to try to iron out issues like these before posting a challenge.

Comment: @Shaggy I test the shortest code, if it pass then it is the answer if not, then I write a comment for them about the failure and then test the next shortest answer.

Comment: @asmgx You still haven't actually added the specs to the question, so it's not their fault that their solution doesn't match them. By community consensus, rules made in comments aren't valid until they are put in the actual question for this reason

Comment: Suggested test case: `Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaads Of The Same Letters -> 1d1f1h1m1r2L3s3t4e23a29O` (or any other test case with a letter more than 9 times)

Comment: I've VTCed this as unclear until all issues raised in the comments have been addressed in the spec. Please ping me when they have and I'll retract my vote (or cast my vote to reopen).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0 [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/58974), 14 bytes

```
f\l üv ñÊ®ÌiZÊ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ZlxsIPx2IPHKrsxpWso=&input=IktpdGthdCBUYW5nbyIKLVA=)

```
f\l üv ñÊ®ÌiZÊ     :Implicit input of string
                   > e.g., "Kitkat Tango"

f                  :Split to an array of characters
 \l                :  Matching RegEx /[a-z]/gi
                   > ["K","i","t","k","a","t","T","a","n","g","o"]

    ü              :Sort & group (Preserves original order within each group)
     v             :  By lowercase
                   > [["a","a"],["g"],["i"],["K","k"],["n"],["o"],["t","t","T"]]

       ñ           :Sort
        Ê          :  By length
                   > [["g"],["i"],["n"],["o"],["a","a"],["K","k"],["t","t","T"]]

         ®         :Map each Z
          Ì        :  Last element of Z
                   >   ["g","i","n","o","a","k","T"]
           i       :  Prepend
            ZÊ     :    Length of Z
                   >   ["1g","1i","1n","1o","2a","2k","3T"]

                   :Implicitly join & output
                   > "1g1i1n1o2a2k3T"
```

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>19</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Kevin Cruijssen*

```
áΣl}.γl}éεgyθJ}J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9vc2FiaWX//8OhzqNsfS7Os2x9w6nOtWd5zrhKfUr//0RhdGFiYXNlIFBhcnRpdGlvbnMgVGFzaw)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVvn/8MJzi3Nq9c5tzqk9vPLc1vTKczu8ar3@V9orKejaKSjZ6/z3zizJTixRCEnMS8/nckksSUxKLE5VCEgsKsksyczPKwbKFGcDAA)

**Explanation**

```
á                  # keep only letters in input
 Σl}               # sort by lower-case
    .γl}           # group by lower-case
        é          # sort by length (stable)
         ε    }    # map each to
          g        # its length
             J     # joined with
           yθ      # the last letter
               J   # join to string
```

Comment: You can save a byte by changing the `‚` (pair with) to a `«` (concat/merge), so one of the two `J`s (joins) can be removed.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Wow. I feel stupid now :) Why didn't I just move a `J` inside? Edit: Actually, I needed them as a pair in the 19-byte version and I didn't think to change it when I made the 17 one :P

Comment: You might be able to drop the second `J`oin, depending on the answer to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/178888/generate-a-password#comment431176_178888)

Comment: -1 by changing `εgyθJ}J` to `vygyθJ`. And another -3 by changing `Σl}.γl}` to `.¡l}` (we now have an actual group-by builtin, yay).

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>66</s> 63 bytes

```perl6
{[~] map {+$_~.tail},sort {+$_,.lc},m:g/<:L>/.classify(&lc){*}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcmxDoIwEADQna@4gVDQpmwORJzcdHBwM4achJKGQknvFtKUX6/G9b118PaU5g0KDW0Kr/0NM64Qjnm3K0ZjoyTn@Q9S2T7KuRnrc3O/1Kq3SGT0Vha2r8IhxkS4gS7zrgLtfCZuhidkeOIyOiEzcUXGD9IAD/Rs2LiFfkmTkOkL)

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                                                             }  # Anon block
                                    m:g/<:L>/  # Match all letters
                                             .classify(&lc)  # Group by lowercase
                                                           {*}  # Get hash values
                     sort {+$_,.lc},  # Sort by array length and lowercase
     map {         },  # Map to
          +$_~.tail  # Concat array length and last letter
 [~]  # Join
```

Answer (score 8):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 105 bytes

```cs
x=>x.Where(char.IsLetter).GroupBy(a=>a%32).OrderBy(a=>(a.Count(),a.Key)).Select(a=>a.Count()+""+a.Last())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU67CsJAEOz9CgkIt6hXaKlJ4RMxoKBgvTmX5FAvsrsB/foYX42NUw3zYpz0nfh6UQU3FmUf8t5qHqoLMWZn@khJoiQa17c4udlDQUzGFch2JSmpEoNdclldJ3eDcYKd4QDsho/Eb8GgnZZVUAM9tGu6A9gdncnpK/31ulHURZuiNBzqUevAXin1gcz7Q5MLDtU8n5ho7fWE2t5jyMtfRADwrz9DxQyF2ltk9erLIM2YnF7d@gE)

Thanks to dana for bringing it down to 105 bytes from 138 bytes.

Comment: why not just `.OrderBy(a=>a)` ?

Comment: [105](https://tio.run/##hU67CsJAEOz9CgkIt6hXaKlJ4RMxoKBgvTmX5FAvsrsB/foYX42NUw3zYpz0nfh6UQU3FmUf8t5qHqoLMWZn@khJoiQa17c4udlDQUzGFch2JSmpEoNdclldJ3eDcYKd4QDsho/Eb8GgnZZVUAM9tGu6A9gdncnpK/31ulHURZuiNBzqUevAXin1gcz7Q5MLDtU8n5ho7fWE2t5jyMtfRADwrz9DxQyF2ltk9erLIM2YnF7d@gE "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")?

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>67</s> <s>66</s> <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```
\P{L}

O$`.
$l$0
ir`\1*(.)
$.0$1
N`\d+.
```

-25 bytes and a minor bug-fix thanks to *@Neil*.
-2 bytes thanks to *@Neil* and *@Shaggy* together.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/Pyag2qeWi8tfJUGPSyVHRY0rsyghxlBLQ0@TS0VPTcWQyy8hJkVb7/9/l8SSxKTE4lSFgMSiksySzPy8YoWQxOJsBQfFeEMjYwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8D8moNqnlovLXyVBj0slR0WNK7MoIcZQS0NPk0tFT03FkMsvISZFW@//f@/MkuzEEoWQxLz0fC6XxJLEpMTiVIWAxKKSzJLM/LxioExxtoKDYryhkTEA).

**Explanation:**

Remove everything except for upper- and lowercase letters:
i.e. `Kitkat Tango 123!` → `KitkatTango`

```
\P{L}
```

Sort the individual letters case-insensitive ([thanks to *@MartinEnder* for this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/148228/sort-an-option-string/148231?noredirect=1#comment431171_148231)):
i.e. `KitkatTango` → `aagiKknottT`

```
O$`.
$l$0
```

Capture every chunk of case-insensitive repeated adjacent letters:
i.e. `aagiKknottT` → [`aa`,`g`,`i`,`Kk`,`n`,`o`,`ttT`]

```
ir`\1*(.)
```

Prepend the length of every match, and only keep the last letter of every chunk:
i.e. [`aa`,`g`,`i`,`Kk`,`n`,`o`,`ttT`] → `2a1g1i2k1n1o3T`

```
$.0$1
```

Sort the numbers and letter groups based on the numbers:
`2a1g1i2k1n1o3T` → `1g1i1n1o2a2k3T`

```
N`\d+.
```

After which the result is output implicitly.

Comment: Are you sure that's a bug? Is it not just sorting lexicographically? (`"aA" < "aa"`)

Comment: @Shaggy You're right it's not a bug. I meant a bug in my program, not in Retina itself. It's behaving as you would expect indeed. I've edited it to 'problem'. If only I could do `O$i` to sort case-insensitive, just like I can `L`ist or `m`atch case-insensitive by using `$i`..

Comment: @Shaggy Fixed. Apparently there is a case-insensitive sort now. :)

Comment: And a hell of a saving! Nice :) I was going to suggest sorting each pair by its first character, otherwise, if Retina can do that.

Comment: @Shaggy I'm not sure if it can. Because the `\w` and `.` in the ``O`\w.`` were used to indicate that we're sorting pairs of characters. Not sure if we can sort every pair of characters, but only sort it based on the first character. But ah well, Martin's suggestion to sort each character based on a substitution (which is the lowercase variant of the match) works like a charm. :)

Comment: Can it be done in [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/PzomPCYlPpaLy18lQY9LJUdFjSuzKCHGUEtDT5NLRU9NxZDLLyEmRVvv/3@XxJLEpMTiVIWAxKKSzJLM/LxihZDE4mwA "Retina – Try It Online") or am I missing something?

Comment: @Neil Ah nice! Btw, where in the [documents](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language) can I find the lowercase `r` builtin? Nice use of the `N` sorting.. Completely forgot about that one for some reason, even though I remember using it once before in a Retina answer of mine (also suggested by you at the time iIrc xD)

Comment: https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language#regex-modifiers

Comment: `[\W\d_]`? Does Retina not have a character class to match letters only?

Comment: @Shaggy Not that I can see on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions

Comment: @Shaggy Not that I know of, except when using [the Transliterate builtin](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language#transliterate-t-and-y), which seems to have builtins for `0-9`, `02468`, `13579`, `0-9A-F`, `0-9a-f`, `A-Z`, `a-z`, `AEIOU`, `aeiou`, `_0-9A-Za-z`,and `<sp>-~` (`<sp>` being a space). Why these builtins aren't available for the entire code with a prefix of some sort I don't know.

Comment: @Shaggy Actually reading further, `\P{L}` might work, which saves 2 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl 5 (`-n`), <s>74</s>, <s>68</s>, <s>66</s>, 65 bytes

-6 bytes changing `-p` to `-n` and using `say` instead of `$_=join"",`
-2 bytes thanks to Abigail using `\pL` instead of `[a-z]`
-1 byte thanks to Kjetil S. removing `i` flag no more necessary after using `\pL`

```
s/\pL/($h{lc$&}+=1).=$&/ge;say sort{$a-$b||lc$a cmp lc$b}values%h
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##PYqxDsIgFAB3v4KBNm0MxQ6dGjY3NXFwdHk0pDRFIDw0MW1/XSQO3nSXnFfBdKnQoqr7hPzuz7yiejEDLbe9aOtG0JKPqkd4E3QhLhQYleuaByDDw5MscnuBeSosdEqnKc4QyQ3s6P7sjhBBAipyhRCnODmLecH54/wvErt0zaFNzH4B)

58 bytes, in case there is no more than 9 occurence of each character

```
s/\pL/($h{lc$&}+=1).=$&/ge;say sort{lc$a cmp lc$b}values%h
```

Comment: @Abigail, thank you, in the second program it was an oversight a after update

Comment: Shave a byte by replacing `/gie` with `/ge`. Since `\pL` is case insensitive.

Comment: @KjetilS. thank you, updated

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, <s>27</s> <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
ssrD0m,lded.gr0k@+Gr1G
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ssrD0m%2Clded.gr0k%40%2BGr1G&input=%22Database+Partitions+Tasksssssssssss%22&debug=0).

```
ssrD0m,lded.gr0k@+Gr1GQ   Implicit: Q=eval(input()), G=lowercase alphabet
                          Trailing Q inferred
                   r1G    Uppercase alphabet
                 +G       Concatenate with lowercase alphabet
                @     Q   Keep those characters in Q which are also in the above
           .g             Group the remaining characters, as k, using:
             r0k             Convert k to lowercase
                              (Grouping preserves relative order)
     m                    Map the sorted groups, as d, using:
       ld                   Length of d
      ,                     Pair the above with...
         ed                 ... last element of d
   D                      Sort the above...
  r 0                     ... by their lowercase values
ss                        Flatten, then concatenate the result of the above into a string, implicit print
```

*Edit: Golfed 3 bytes by ordering by character before group, previous version: `sm+ldedo,lNr0eN.gr0kf}r0TGQ`*

*Edit 2: Golfed off another 2 bytes by formatting output before any ordering, previous version: `sm+ldedlD.gr0krD0f}r0TGQ`*

*Edit 3: Golfed off another byte by changing the filter, thanks to @FryAmTheEggman. Also had to fix a bug when OP clarified that a single letter can appear more than 9 times, which added a byte back on :o( Previous version: `srD0m+lded.gr0kf}r0TGQ`*

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 105 bytes

```python
s=input()
t=s.upper()
for n,c in sorted((t.count(i),i)for i in{*t}if'@'<i<'['):print(n,end=s[t.rfind(c)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fco9CgIxEEDh3lOkm0SWNHayAQsPYLHdYhHzg4MwCZlJIeLZY@wefK@@5VnoNAY7pNpFm4M4tr3W1Gbn0hQtQSEpLk1S1FpsKJ1Eo1nQ/B2nfo7yxQwXWHGFHcy5NpwPLYmi411sy0hRB3M3Y8DVi394Turmm6BgIVab5xf8AA)

-1 thanks to [ArBo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/82577/arbo).

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>102</s> <s>96</s> <s>93</s> 87 bytes

```
""<>Map@ToString/@Sort[(r=Reverse)/@Tally[r@#/." "->Nothing,Equal@@ToLowerCase@{##}&]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FU7Pa8IwFL77VzxSEJVqeNXdpgR0p7lRZm6lh6fENrQ2W/JURunf3mXH7/d3I67NjdheaLzCFkYhXncf9K20O7G3XSXVyXkuZn77ZR7GBzOXSlPb/hZeJXIlQCx3n47raE3ffu7Uqhg9uqfxewpG9UkyTMtyOlIs78W75YYYNHWVEymIAzGdow9y8mzZui5EMTRiACkh/ij2NXm6cFwuJ5M8PuLiKhVFALMF9FihxQ5dRlmz1ingGQ9osPnnMEef2XXY6BcaYDEf/wA)

```
Tally[r@#/." "->Nothing,Equal@@ToLowerCase@{##}&]      Start with a char list
        #/." "->Nothing                                Remove spaces
      r@                                               Reverse the result
Tally[                 ,Equal@@ToLowerCase@{##}&]
                                             Make a list of letters and multiplicities,
                                             where two letters are considered the same if
                                             their lowercase values are equal. Then:

""<>Map@ToString/@Sort[(r=Reverse)/@ ... ]&
                       (r=Reverse)           Reverse each {letter, freq} to {freq,letter}.
                                             Then the standard Wolfram order function sorts
                                               lower frequencies first, with ties broken by
                                               by letters earlier in the alphabet,
                  Sort[                  ]     exactly what we want.

    Map@ToString/@                           @ has higher precedence than /@, so
                                               this effectively does Map[Map[ToString]].
""<>                                         StringJoin the nested list into a single string.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 116 bytes

```python
def f(s):a=s.lower();return''.join(`n`+s[a.rfind(c)] for n,c in sorted((a.count(c),c)for c in set(a)if c.isalpha()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc0xSwNBEIbh3l8xYHE7GBb2oo1il84mxXUiZLK3m4wXZo6dCeKvPy8K1s/38s3fflbpl2UsFWowfKZXixf9Ki3gSyt@bdJ18VNZwkEOD/ZOsVWWMWT8gKoNZJOBBUyblzEEilmv4itvMt78T4sHQq6QIxtd5jMFRFzmxuLrbffGPpHDQHLSDuE@nRInSdpTP22Hu//djpyOZAX21JydVWyNbPptjmmXSppuXdqn1vPWHocnWn4A)

Comment: The output for `Database Partitions Task` is not equal to `1b1D1e1k1n1o1P1r2i3s4T5a`

Comment: @mdahmoune thanks, should be fixed.

Comment: `In the output, use the case of the last occurrence in the input` you'll need `rfind` instead of `find` for this. `...] for` can become `...]for` to offset that though.

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>220</s> <s>196</s> 206 bytes

```
func[s][a: charset[#"a"-#"z"#"A"-#"Z"]trim/all form sort/skip collect[foreach c sort
unique reverse rejoin parse s[collect[any[keep[a]| skip]]][i: 0
foreach d s[if(c% 32)=(d% 32)[i: i + 1]]keep i keep c]]2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYwxT8MwEIX3/IrTRZWKECqULRIDMxti4nTDyTlTN6kdbAepFf89tSOViVve0733vqj98q49cWM7WOzsDSUm6cAcJCbN1KLgQ4sXbPG1mk/kHN1pJ@MINsQTpBDzLg1uAhPGUU2m8lYxBzBr1szefc8KUX@0EIseg/MwVTwkuo3En2lQnUj4FyqOmcl18NjccH1pO7s1G3je371s@1VrxcE9PDHXdfGrGOY9L1N0PoMFfHN5kAwf4r/C32Hzb47LFQ)

Thanks to Shaggy for finding a bug.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>114/113</s> 105 bytes

<sup>-9 bytes thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni) (using list-comprehension and `(||)` instead of `filter` with `elem` & shorten `length` to get rid of ugly `zip`)!</sup>

```hs
f s=id=<<[show(h r)++[last r]|l<-[1..h s],a<-['A'..'Z'],r<-[[x|x<-s,x==a||x==[a..]!!32]],h r==l]
h=length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHRSsMwFIbv@xRnRehGu0I2vRnNhbgLUZGBA8FaJLNZG1qTkZyxbvTaB/ARfZF6OgWnN@Gc5P@/8ycphatkXXfdGhxXOU@S1JVmNyzBjsIwrYVDsFlbJ@OUxXEJLosE1cFlEMfBU5BFlrq0aZtk7KKGc9G2tKYijrPBYDrJsohInNeZV/Ja6gLL7k0oDRxy4wH4tworgbAUujA@fL5/wM2WRvqsYIppZiZiUk2Xfi@dCxQr4SQshEWFymhHPlf9sa3YnElW9Va2YHaipu58eSF6wLCX3RsslS5GQDeFQuKV0Sg1Os9rfjEHUrewB87hQEk3W3xAe6fhDPq3gQbCEL6n@n153NwfPUSXdqcoJIe1UDVZfNls5CvKfHaiPhwRz1gYnP2D7Igg@@GwhuYn1Qt1J/mGdDLqrunfTASPxtb54As)

Comment: 107 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHRSsMwFIbv9xRnRWhLtZBNQbZlIO5CVGTgQLAWl9m0Dc2SkZyxbuzaB/ARfZGaTsHp3fmT///OH1IyW3Epm6akkqsCy04OlmYa5OgsIXFcgk2HzM3@lR/H/rOfDo1TuZDITTDnki/nbJAkLI7TbrffS0PnTy73JRhKZToe21JvAqfCKEokswgmbZZMKKCQ6Q6AdyewYggzpgrtwef7B9yunc0jBRFEEd1jvao/81rrhCFbMMthygwKFFpZl7PVn9iCTAgnVRslU2J6om/PZxesBQSt7UFjKVQRAh2NoOB4rRVyhbbTqX8xO@fewxYohZ1rulrjI5p7BSfQvgdqiCL43uq14@Fwe8g4Ojcb4UpSyJmQLuLxesXfkGeDI/fugHjBQuPgH2TjCLxdDjnUP61enTrqF7ibsLlxP6dP4UkbmXW/AA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: 105: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHRSsMwFIbv@xRnRehGu0I2vRnNhbgLUZGBA8FaJLNZG1qTkZyxbvTaB/ARfZF6OgWnN@Gc5P@/8ycphatkXXfdGhxXOU@S1JVmNyzBjsIwrYVDsFlbJ@OUxXEJLosE1cFlEMfBU5BFlrq0aZtk7KKGc9G2tKYijrPBYDrJsohInNeZV/Ja6gLL7k0oDRxy4wH4tworgbAUujA@fL5/wM2WRvqsYIppZiZiUk2Xfi@dCxQr4SQshEWFymhHPlf9sa3YnElW9Va2YHaipu58eSF6wLCX3RsslS5GQDeFQuKV0Sg1Os9rfjEHUrewB87hQEk3W3xAe6fhDPq3gQbCEL6n@n153NwfPUSXdqcoJIe1UDVZfNls5CvKfHaiPhwRz1gYnP2D7Igg@@GwhuYn1Qt1J/mGdDLqrunfTASPxtb54As "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Laikoni: Now shorter than with imports, very nice!!

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 103 bytes

```scala
_.filter(_.isLetter).groupBy(_%32).values.map(l=>l.size+""+l.last).toSeq.sortBy(_.toLowerCase).mkString
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5NawIxEIbPu79iWBASLHOwt8IuWHpsQbD3ZdTpEo1Jmhm1Kv72dKngoaf3ObxfsiZPJa62vFb4IBeAf5TDRmCeElzrqq6O5GHgwJmUFyRyinnzAkvNLgzQdg8qPX45r5xNj07eWUe0OOR4SK9n00@eZxbHrgML7ikZ33YexV142jRTj55ELWpc8jdKzDpGpO2M/FmexFrc7@5LpUqjqA/m/yvTvJHSioRhQVmduhgEPkl2jbX1rZRf)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
fØẠµŒlĠLÞịµL,Ṫ)
```

A full program printing the password as specified (as a monadic Link it yields a list of lists each containing an integer and a character).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT0Awv9qZWxsef//ZsOY4bqgwrXFkmzEoEzDnuG7i8K1TCzhuaop////RGF0YWJhc2UgUGFydGl0aW9ucyBUYXNr)**

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 15 bytes

No problems with imports when using Husk, therefore we can make use of the various handy functions such as `groupOn`, `sortOn`, `toLower` etc:

```
ṁ§:osL→ÖLSġÖ_f√
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9odXNr///huYHCpzpvc0zihpLDlkxTxKHDll9m4oia////S2l0a2F0IFRhbmdv) or [try them all!](https://tio.run/##AVwAo/9odXNr/23Cp28rYCsiIC0@ICJzb3PigoHCtv/huYHCpzpvc0zihpLDlkxTxKHDll9m4oia////S2l0a2F0IFRhbmdvCkRhdGFiYXNlIFBhcnRpdGlvbnMgVGFzaw)

### Explanation

```
ṁ§:(sL)→ÖLSġÖ_f√  -- example input: "Kitkat Tango"
              f√  -- `filter isAlpha`: "KitkatTango"
          S  _    -- apply _ to .. then ..
            Ö     -- | sortOn: `sortOn toLower`
           ġ      -- | groupOn: `groupOn toLower`
                  -- .. compose: `groupOn toLower . sortOn toLower`
                  -- `sortOn toLower` (stable): "aagiKknottT"
                  -- `groupOn toLower`: ["aa","g","i","Kk","n","o","ttT"]
        ÖL        -- `sortOn length` (stable): ["g","i","n","o","aa","Kk","ttT"]
ṁ                 -- map and flatten (`concatMap`)
 §                -- | fork argument ..
       →          -- | | `last`: ['g','i','n','o','a','k','T']
   (sL)           -- | | `show . length`: ["1","1","1","1","2","2","3"]
  :               -- | .. and `snoc`: ["1g","1i","1n","1o","2a","2k","3T"]
                  -- : "1g1i1n1o2a2k3T"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 28 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
(∊⍤∧⌊(⊂⍕⍤≢,⊢/)⍤⊢⌸⊢)'\PL'⎕R''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X@NRR9ej3iWPOpY/6unSeNTV9Kh3KojfuUjnUdcifU0Qu2vRo54dQFJTPSbAR/1R39QgdfX/aY/aJjzq7QPyPP0fdTUfWm/8qG0ikBcc5AwkQzw8g/@nKah7Z5ZkJ5YohCTmpefDgToA)

`'\PL'` non-letters
`⎕R` PCRE **R**eplaced with
`''` empty strings

`(`…`)` apply the following tacit function:

`⌊` with the lowercase as keys,
 …`⌸` apply the below tacit function to each key and its corresponding set of values, namely
 `⊢` the argument:

`(`…`)` apply the following tacit function
  `⍤` to
  `⊢` the list of values:

`⊢/` the last value

…`,` prepend the following to that:

`⍕` the stringification
    `⍤` of
    `≢` the tally

`⊂` enclose (to treat character list as single string)

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)
 `⍤` the
 `∧` sorted-ascending version of that

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 127 bytes

```javascript
s=>[...s].sort(o=(x,y)=>p(0+x,36)-p(0+y,36),p=parseInt).join``.match(/([a-z])\1*/ig).map(x=>(l=x.length)+x[l-1]).sort(o).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xTsMwFEV3vsKb/UjiUiGxIGeiQ8XCwJZG6iM4qVvjZ9lPyOXngyvBdI/uke494zfmKbnIXaBPu85mzaYftNZ51JkSKzKqtFcwfVQPTWkfn6C70fVGbTQRU7b7wKDP5MLxqL@Qp5PaqAG7nxEO2/uNW6C2URXTK2@K9jYsfIKmDL7bjvB38z@wshnkq@MLsnjHsJBshXxBxg/MVrxhYseOQq4yX@T4fMd6prTDesqmn6ohb7WnRbFohDwEWWNWDADrLw)

- `parseInt(numberAsString, radix)` will try to parse integer in the beginning of string. For example, `parseInt('120px', 10)` will output 120. When parsing failed, it returns `NaN` instead. We connect an `'0'` to the beginning of each character so it will return `0` for any non numeric-alpha characters. And we can sort same letters together and non-alpha character to the beginning by this algorithm.
- After `sort` and `join`, `"Hello world!123"` would become `" !123deHllloorw"`. An matching against `/([a-z])\1*/ig` will ignore any non-alpha character and split the string into chunks with same letters. `.
- `map` convert `"aaa"` to `"3a"` as required in the question.
- The second sort use same function as the first one. Thanks to the number system, `"3b"` would be less than `"12a"` in base 36 just as we expect: It compare counts first (`n div 36`), and compare the letter later (`n mod 36`).
- Finally `join` them together.

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 146 bytes

```javascript
f=(s,...a)=>(s=s.replace(/[^a-z]/ig,''))?f(s.replace(RegExp(s[c=0],'ig'),x=>(l=++c+x,'')),...a,l):a.sort((x,y)=>p(x,36)-p(y,36),p=parseInt).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY0/TwMhGId3PwUbLzmOqk0caqiLHYyLMW7nmb4ih7QECLwxV7/8Sbs4PcPz@3PAH6ym@Ex9TF92WSYNVSqlUOgtVF1VsTmgsbAaPrD/HVfeSc6FeJjg371at5sz1MHo61Fy77iQc@sH3XWmmy@Fy6gMYoOqpkIAszy1j9y4vhN9htOZMuuMpdqnSEIdko/7/UJ64M@ejkjsDaNLXDL@iISfWC17wUKefIq1yXo8u5vbNR/vr0hNqezQfAPprWmBFKwKyQGxjvH3yBsmICHE8gc)

Comment: Why not submit the shorter solution as your main solution? Also, it can be 2 bytes shorter as it's not recursive.

Comment: @Shaggy Ah, totally forgot to remove `f=`. The first one used to be shorter. But it gets 4 bytes more since OP asked the output may be empty string. And I just kept them there...

Comment: @Shaggy OK, just find out the second one may be even more shorter. And I placed it as first.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>223</s> <s>209</s> 301 bytes

```java
s->{int i=32,t;String M[]=new String[i],r,R="";for(var c:s)M[c%32]+=c>64&c<91|c>96&c<123?c:R;for(;i-->0;M[i]=(t=r.length()-4)>0?t+r.split(R)[t+3]:R)r=M[i]+R;java.util.Arrays.sort(M);for(var p:M)R+=p;return R;}
```

+92 bytes as a fix for inputs with more than 9 of a single letter.. Will see if I can bring that down again with a different approach.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lVJRa9swEH7Pr7gZNiRsizQphcazu25921yG1zfXjIuiJEocyUiXlNDlt2dyMWMPXWH3IHTS932n@04bPGC6WWzPskXvoURtnkcA2pByS5QK7vsU4Ac5bVYgmVyjqxvwPAvnp1FYPCFpCfdgIIezT4vnwAadTycJZQOvrJvcqKdBptZN4pIqj6JsaR07oAM587ys5fvppIlzWVxdfpAfry9@yeL6KuwuJtMbOate0JlO02KclUEkZ5Q70SqzojXj6SUvxjcUO@G7VhOreE3xtJlV3OU9Oq6yTehW7Em34tY5PHrhrSNWJgyTOU@L/oWfj6QYG8fIhVNdGyy4bVsWPT7eRUkUcS6k3XXo1INlf8Pn/4Bz/qfFblbyKs67zCnaOwNVdjpnvYHdft4GAwcfD1YvYBfmwAazGkA@DOHoSe2E3ZPowhW1hhkhWfRV0xYJHtCsbCTIfgkzemmQ9fXfpN4h4Ry9gu/oSJO2xgcdv4VP734G1/9T7Zt9I/DVWHiwS6C1Ao87Ba2i8PNeLXsanc6/AQ)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                        // Method with character-array parameter and String return-type
  int i=32,                 //  Index-integer, starting at 32
      t;                    //  Temp-integer, uninitialized
  String M[]=new String[i], //  Create a String-array of size 32, filled with null by default
         R="",              //  Result-String, starting empty
         r;                 //  Temp-String, uninitialized
  for(var c:s)              //  Loop over the characters of the input-array:
    M[c%32]+=               //   Append the string at index code-point of `c` modulo-32 with:
     c>64&c<91|c>96&c<123?  //    If the character is a letter:
      c                     //     Append the character
     :                      //    Else:
      R;                    //     Append an empty String
  for(;i-->0                //  Loop `i` in the range (32, 0]:
      ;                     //    After every iteration:
       M[i]=                //     Replace the String at index `i` with:
        (t=r.length()-4)    //      Set `t` to the length of String `r` minus 4
                            //      (the minus 4 is for the prepended "null")
         >0?                //      If this length minus 4 is larger than 0:
          t                 //       Set the String to this length minus 4
          +r.split(R)[t+3]  //       Appended with the last character of `r` as String
         :                  //      Else:
          R)                //       Make the String at index `i` empty
    r=M[i]                  //   Set `r` to the `i`'th String
          +R;               //  Converted to String
                            // (null becomes "null", to prevent NullPointerException-errors)
  java.util.Arrays.sort(M,  //  Now sort the array of Strings on:
   (a,b)->                  //   For each pair of two Strings:
     new Byte(              //    Convert the first String to a number
      (0+a).replaceAll("\\D",""))
                            //    after we've added a leading 0 and removed all non-digits
    .compareTo(             //   And compare it to:
     new Byte(              //    The second String converted to a number
      (0+b).replaceAll("\\D",""))));
                            //    after we've added a leading 0 and remove all non-digits
  for(var p:M)              //  Loop over the Strings of the array:
    R+=p;                   //   And append each to the result-String `R`
  return R;}                //  And finally return the result-String `R`
```

Comment: @Shaggy Dang.. fixed at the cost of 92 bytes.. >.< Will see if I can golf it down again by not using a Comparator to sort but sort manually myself later on..

Comment: Ouch! Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift 4.2.1/Xcode 10.1](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), <s>1054</s> <s>1050</s> <s>1048</s> <s>370</s> <s>368</s> 364 bytes

```swift
s.map{String($0)}.filter{$0.rangeOfCharacter(from:.letters) != nil}.reversed().reduce(into:[String:Int]()){d,s in if let l=[s.uppercased(),s.lowercased()].first(where:{d[$0] != nil}){d[l]=d[l]!+1}else{d[s]=1}}.sorted{let c=$0.value-$1.value;return c==0 ?$0.key.compare($1.key,options:.caseInsensitive) == .orderedAscending:c<0}.map{"\($0.value)\($0.key)"}.joined()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVE9T8MwEN35FUfVwRbFSiWmQEAIhIQYQIKtZDDxpZimduS7tEJRfnu5tMCEWKx3X@/ePdPW13y28@s2Joa72AVn2cdwVHehgiUGTJbxyRJtY3KKcnjm5MNSw@nlN4QeEnKXwo7M2rb9IaummR5M7RvG1E8zk2xY4mN9826TrSSn6hTXuWmQJSANxwUE3wwm4UZidEoLdF2FygeO@eLAmt8HLpXWvZsR@AC@BmGApliQ6doWU2X3szMyTdz@hqUIScRq@44J894tpln5s1G4Fk1ZjM/xyXzAhlAyVBbzYTAkrqDrxx1VIVdsbNPh6XR@AOeHu6VUZHAl5RV@miquW5tQSZOEs9iOdlJuRin3gTCQZ79BDUUBRjwVRe6aKgxuvK@6yIa9i5NX9bNP76GQ6clgPqIP40m74agVR1j99UeTB88ry/AipseJ1v@13lq2b6INnmxivxcrc7SSsd0X)

@KevinCruijssen also removed some spaces.

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! I don't know Swift, but it seems you forgot to remove some spaces, and you can also golf all `false` to `0>1` and `true` to `1>0`. [Try it online **1027 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/y9g3ltjw). Probably loads more can be golfed, like the duplicated `if let v=$0.key.escaped(asASCII:0>1).lowercased().unicodeScalars.first?.value{return v<$1.key.value}else{return 0>1}` you have, but I'll leave that to someone who actually knows Swift.

Comment: Also, if you haven't seen it yet: [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5285/52210) and [Tips for golfing in Swift](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79203/52210) might be interesting to read through. Again welcome, and enjoy your stay! :)

Comment: Hello @KevinCruijssen. Thanks for tips, I removed `true` and `false` from my answer.

Comment: Nice, you've golfed it quite a lot from your initial 1000+ bytes. :) I see 6 more spaces that can be removed after/before all `=`-assigns: [Try it online **364 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/y9zrd7tq). Enjoy your stay! :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 30 bytes

```
Ｆ⌈Ｅβ№↧θιＦβ¿⁼№↧θκ⊕ι⁺⊕ι§Φθ⁼↧λκ±¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7PCsIwDIfvPkWOGdSDZ0/iHxio7OALZFumZV3r2lT39rUOQQQDye@QLx9pbuQbRyalznnAE016iEPOO9YKti5awaN7sm8oMI6FAl3kgpmuC9Ad4H6MZAL@g/vcpW08D2yFW3wfQ@V1BisTA/7uFGyktC1PeNBG2OOo4CP/as2szePMVxLG1fufdUo7EqozABV50aKdDXCh0C/S8mHoBQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⌈Ｅβ№↧θι
```

Run through the lowercase alphabet and find the highest character count in the lowercased input. Loop over the implicit range. (The loop actually goes from `0` to `n-1` so I have to increment the loop variable at each use.)

```
Ｆβ
```

Loop over the lowercase alphabet again.

```
¿⁼№↧θκ⊕ι
```

If the count of the current letter is equal to the outer loop value...

```
⁺⊕ι§Φθ⁼↧λκ±¹
```

Concatenate the current count with the last occurrence of the current letter and implicitly print.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
fØẠŒuL,ṪƊƙ$ŒuÞ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/t8IyHuxYcnVTqo/Nw56pjXcdmqgA5h@f9///fJbEkMSmxOFUhILGoJLMkMz@vWCEksTgbAA)

Full program.

Answer (score 1):

### NodeJS, 299 bytes, -6 bytes thank to @tsh

Not so beauty but it work!

```
(x,l={},g=p=>p.charCodeAt(),q=p=>p.toLowerCase())=>Object.entries([...x[R='replace'](/[^a-z]/gi,'')].reduce((m,n)=>(r=q(n),l[r]=g(n)>96?1:0,{...m,[r]:-~m[r]}),{})).sort((a,b)=>a[1]^b[1]?a[1]-b[1]:g(q(a[0]))-g(q(b[0]))).map(([m,n])=>[n,m]).join``[R](/,/g,'')[R](/[a-z]/g,v=>l[v]?q(v):v.toUpperCase())
```

### Javascript (ES8) (Firefox or Chrome), 294 bytes, -1 byte thank to @tsh

With new `.flat` method, I can save 10 bytes:

```
(x,l={},g=p=>p.charCodeAt(),q=p=>p.toLowerCase())=>Object.entries([...x[R='replace'](/[^a-z]/gi,'')].reduce((m,n)=>(r=q(n),l[r]=g(n)>96?1:0,{...m,[r]:-~m[r]}),{})).sort((a,b)=>a[1]^b[1]?a[1]-b[1]:g(q(a[0]))-g(q(b[0]))).map(([m,n])=>[n,m]).flat().join``[R](/[a-z]/g,v=>l[v]?q(v):v.toUpperCase())
```

Try this online:
https://repl.it/repls/ConcernedHorribleHypothesis

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG. It would be nice if you provided a way to test your submission, like linking to an online interpreter.

Comment: @JonathanFrech I just added test cases, thank you!

Comment: `.replace` x 3 times -> `[R='replace]` and `[R]` x 2 times

Comment: `.charCodeAt(0)` -> `.charCodeAt()` (`0` is default)

Comment: @tsh Thank you a lot for all your good tips, I just updated my answer!

Comment: @tsh your solution beats my solution, btw I upvoted it but I got error that my reputation is not enough so it will not appear, but I want to inform you that I loved this and I learn a lot so I upvoted your solution!

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>131</s> 129 bytes

```r
cat(paste0(N<-by(X<-utf8ToInt(gsub('[^a-z]','',scan(,''),T)),G<-X%%32,length),L<-intToUtf8(by(X,G,tail,1),T))[order(N,L)],sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/NasMwEITvfoolIVgC2UR2Cz04t0AoDSEHFwJpCmtXdoWNZKQN6Q99dtduqWmhexzmm5l1/RwuDjvwJRomwpCDNoBQnU1J2hogC9i29gIKvVYOSHnSpg6q1Y@F0Qvx95HPokmL45gPel8isQ49qSXbZVHxyg5ZdKbqJre3hljtzwULj48YvZ3CoVxMK0TOudhk0WGxSBPRKlPTMxfbLNKGcns/JLAxTGwEoW6F/AKO1j0px3Ziy0/Cq241BPUfQVCx2Z2mBglyNLWdcZiDrKWWRtoEkybNg3Fn@GBCPprXSFigV7BHR3r8xw@kb77BQq6lks0Iy710iU79VX6NfyN@9033T7Fc2v4T)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 158 bytes

```julia
¬t=(c=Dict();C=Dict();for i=eachmatch(r"\w",t);l=i.match;k=lowercase(l);c[k]=get(c,k,0)+1;C[k]=l;end;*(["$v$(C[k])" for (v,k)=sort([(v,k) for (k,v)=c])]...))
```

Original ungolfed version with same logic:

```julia
function password(text)
    letter_counts = Dict()
    cases = Dict()

    for i in eachmatch(r"\w", text)
        letter = i.match[1]
        letter_key = lowercase(letter)
        letter_counts[letter_key] = get(letter_counts, letter_key, 0) + 1
        cases[letter_key] = letter
    end

    sorted_counts = sort([(value, key) for (key, value) in letter_counts])

    return string(["$v$(cases[k])" for (v,k) in sorted_counts]...)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY4xDsIwEAR7XhFZFHdgRVBbrqCjoaALKQ5jwNjYyDkCj@IVfCwkIAq61exotedbcDR/dN3ryRqMXjrDgGrxC4eUC6ctmdOF2Jwgi@1dSEYVtCs/SHkd0t1mQ42FgMpUvtZHy2CklzOcztViIEHZuFcTqMS4HcOAUBTDOrTSo25SZqg@@Uu9bFGbGuuyLBG70TW7yCHC6wli5dgTFxuKxyQQ/7olMe36K8WaMjt2KTa92Pje694)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6, <s>86</s> 82 bytes

```
{[~] flat map *[0,2],sort map {+$^b,$^a,$b[*-1]},kv classify &lc,.comb: /<alpha>/}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Rebol, <strike>149</strike>, 146 bytes

```
f: func[s][l: charset[#"a"- #"z"#"A"- #"Z"]rejoin sort/skip collect[parse sort s[any[copy t[copy o l any o](keep length? t keep last t)| skip]]]2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BSwQxDIXv@yueGQ8qLOLqaS8iePMi4slSIVM6s2VKU5p4WPG/jzO7IF5e8j5e8lrsJc9vq8L5edhj@CrBqXd5j3DgptFcR0xbdPRNHT2dtg/yJlu1lsoIlWa3OqWKIDnHYK6udycOdVyOLkg9ws5DkLEwiL@aYqzIsYx2eIThbFkNdv2D9aP3fuc3c23SRwygl2QTG965jEKbP/zMxj0vla/cLFmSoktGp3@Ru93lzf3D5wXNvw)

Ungolfed:

```
f: func [s] [
    l: charset[#"a" - #"z" #"A" - #"Z"]
    rejoin sort/skip collect [
        parse sort s [
            any [
                copy t [copy o l any o] (keep length? t keep last t)
                | skip
            ] 
        ]
    ] 2
]
```

Example usage in Rebol console:

```
>> f "Kitkat Tango"
== "1g1i1n1o2a2k3T"

>> f "Database Partitions Task"
== "1b1D1e1k1n1o1P1r2i3s4T5a"

>> f "12$*34^!"
== ""
```